# Keyring is ignored by apt

Tags: linux, apt, package-management, embedded, gpg

I'm trying implement apt-get on an embedded device. For testing I use one of the Raspbian repositories but apt-get update keeps telling me my keyring has an unsupported file format.

I removed the old keyring and downloaded the new from raspbian.org and added it with apt-key
this resulted in an gpg(v4) file which is in my opinion the correct format for apt_2.2.4 but obviously it looks like apt doesn't like it.

can someone tell me what is happening here and what I'm doing wrong all day?

Greetings

See the Console output below:

```
# rm trusted.gpg

# wget https://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian.public.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
Connecting to archive.raspbian.org (93.93.128.191:443)
writing to stdout
-                    100% |********************************************************************************************************|  1776  0:00:00 ETA
written to stdout
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
OK

# file trusted.gpg
trusted.gpg: PGP/GPG key public ring (v4) created Sun Apr  1 21:02:33 2012 RSA (Encrypt or Sign) 2048 bits MPI=0xcf5b981af19c88b1...

# apt-get update   
Get:1 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian bookworm InRelease [15.0 kB]
Err:1 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian bookworm InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 9165938D90FDDD2E
Reading package lists... Error!
W: http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/bookworm/InRelease: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg are ignored as the file has an unsupported filetype.
W: GPG error: http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian bookworm InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 9165938D90FDDD2E
E: The repository 'http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian bookworm InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: flAbsPath on /var/lib/dpkg/status failed - realpath (2: No such file or directory)
E: Could not open file  - open (2: No such file or directory)
E: Problem opening 
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

# apt-key --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg list
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg
--------------------
pub   rsa2048 2012-04-01 [SC]
      A0DA 38D0 D76E 8B5D 6388  7281 9165 938D 90FD DD2E
uid           [ unknown] Mike Thompson (Raspberry Pi Debian armhf ARMv6+VFP) <mpthompson@gmail.com>
sub   rsa2048 2012-04-01 [E]

# apt --version
apt 2.2.4 ()

# gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.3.3-unknown
libgcrypt 1.9.4-unknown
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GNU GPL-3.0-or-later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: /root/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA, EDDSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
AEAD: EAX, OCB
Hash: SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

Comment: What is the output of `file /etc/apt/trusted.gpg`?  I found [this similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/583266/the-keys-in-the-keyring-etc-apt-trusted-gpg-are-ignored-as-the-file-has-an-un) with the same errors you are getting and there is an answer to remedy the situation.

Comment: hey,
it's in the post the output is
# file trusted.gpg
trusted.gpg: PGP/GPG key public ring (v4) created Sun Apr  1 21:02:33 2012 RSA (Encrypt or Sign) 2048 bits MPI=0xcf5b981af19c88b1...

I found this question too, searching for hours now

Comment: @LexusA `file trusted.gpg` is not the same as `file /etc/apt/trusted.gpg`. Please show output for the latter.

Comment: this is the output of /etc/apt/trusted.gpg